# Load cap file into javacard

Tags: smartcard, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

I'm currently developing c# dll for machine to load applet into java card. I tried to convert file into bytes but the bytes are not the same as the bytes from pyapdutool.

**From PYAPDUTOOL**

> <<80 E8 00 00 FA **C4 82 53 AB** 01 00 27 DE CA FF ED 02 02 04 00 01
>   0A A0 00 00 00 74 4D 79 54 00 10 12 63 6F 6D 2F 70 6E 6D 62 2F 6D 79
>   74 65 6E 74 65 72 61 02 00 21 00 27 00 21 00 35 00 29 02 DA 00 9A 25
>   80 25 56 04 A0 00 00 07 C1 3E C7 00 6A 00 19 25 01 04 04 00 04 00 29
>   04 03 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 01 01 03 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 02 01 03 01
>   07 A0 00 00 00 62 01 02 00 01 07 A0 00 00 00 62 00 01 03 00 35 04 0A
>   A0 00 00 00 74 4A 50 4E 00 10 11 6B 0A A0 00 00 00 74 49 4D 4D 00 10
>   00 80 0A A0 00 00 00 74 4A 50 4A 00 10 08 F4 0A A0 00 00 00 74 4B 4B
>   4D 00 10 1A B2 06 00 9A 00 00 00 80 03 0B 00 0B 04 0E 00 00 00 9C FF
>   FF 00 94 00 A3 02 03 02 5D 02 72 03 71 04 54 04 9C 04 E2 05 45 05 CF
>   06 9A 00 80 03 0B 00 0B 04 0E 00 00 09 10 FF FF 09 08 09 17 0A 77 0A
>   D1 0A E6 0B 01

**From convert .cap file into bytes**

> 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 08 08 00 94 74 F8 4C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 14 00 04 00 4D 45 54 41 2D 49 4E 46 2F 4D 41 4E 49 46 45 53
>   54 2E 4D 46 FE CA 00 00 95 93 DF 6F 9B 30 10 C7 DF ....

From what i know 1st byte (C4) is compulsory for gp and followed by .cap file length (82 53 AB). how can i get the same apdu data as shown in pyapdutool?

Comment: Adding more details increases the chance to get useful answers and reduces probability for downvotes. For a start: Which file? Which pyadutool? How different are the results?

Comment: @Bya I edited and answered your question. Feel free to improve or revert my edit (to return back to your version there is a rollback button in [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51941292/revisions))..Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

Cap file is basically a [jar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) (which in turn resembles a zip file) and its format is described in "Virtual Machine Specification. Java Card Platform Version 3.0.5", section 6 "The CAP File Format" (available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/default-1970005.html)).

It consists of several components (parts) which need to be loaded into the card in correct order (see section 6.3 in the above-mentioned document) -- you can't just take cap file bytes and send them to card.

Loading process is described in "GlobalPlatform Card Specification" (available [here](https://globalplatform.org/specs-library/)) -- see `INSTALL` and `LOAD` commands (you may want to check older versions of this document if your card uses it).

An alternative (and much simpler) way is to have a look at [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) sources, (e.g. [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro/blob/517663bd6bddad5749799d92ea5b7198d072292c/src/main/java/pro/javacard/gp/GlobalPlatform.java#L526) and [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/capfile/blob/dc1e58f24d0a4d411d880fbb84952d0915d2a8ae/src/main/java/pro/javacard/CAPFile.java#L194)).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.. i really appreciate it.. i will study more on this..